# How to refresh terminal after function call

Tags: terminal, zsh, ls, oh-my-zsh, cd

I've written a simple function to search the current folder when I press ctrl+f with exa and peco, after I choose a directory I want to cd into it.

(ll is modified version of ls)

```
pecofunc() {
  ll | peco --layout=bottom-up | read foo 
  foo="${foo##* }"
  if [ -n "$foo" ] 
  then
    builtin cd "$foo"
  fi
  # refresh terminal and end execution
}
zle -N pecofunc pecofunc
bindkey '^f' pecofunc
```

This part works well but after executing it my directory doesn't visually change until I press enter or use other command.

Picture 1
[Terminal before doing anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7mbP.png)

Picture 2 [After pressing ctrl+f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDpyd.png)

Picture 3 [Choosing test2 and pressing enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qXAI.png)

Picture 4 [Pressing enter again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh3Is.png)

Pressing enter again refreshes the folder which I'm in but creates another newline which is unacceptable.

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: Have you tried the `reset` command ?

Comment: @vinalti Also needs another enter press and also takes quite long now to execute.

Comment: Can you try to add `builtin echo ""` OR to add to the shortcut `&& echo ""` after executing the script ?

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue! :(

Answer (score 0):

The key-handler function needs to call `zle -I` after returning from any interactive tools, to invalidate the current display and force ZSH to redraw the command line.

It seems that printing an empty line *before* running the tool can be useful, to avoid overwriting the current prompt in general.

```
pecofunc() {
    echo ""
    ll | peco | read foo
    zle -I
    if ... then cd ... fi
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately the same problem persists. "zle -I" didn't change behavior at all :/ 'echo ""' also just adds 1 more empty line (which I do not want) while not fixing anything.